# move content back and forth like media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move content on window resize.

E.g. when the content is wider than 766 let it stay but if it is smaller move it to another div.

But if someone decides to go into landscape I also want it to check whether it had previously been moved. Therefore I created this script:

```js
var $prevent_filter_issues = 1;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){}, true);
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767 && $prevent_filter_issues == 1) {
        var $but_large_small = $('[id^="product_filters"]').clone().remove();
        $('#sidebar_filter').before($but_large_small);
        var $prevent_filter_issues = 2;
    } else if ($(window).width() > 766 && $prevent_filter_issues == 2) {
        var $but_small_large = $('#sidebar_filter').clone().remove();
        $('[id^="product_filters"]').before($but_small_large);
        var $prevent_filter_issues = 1;
    }
});
```

But this script still does not work. Could any please help me out?

/* EDIT */
This script did the job for me:

```js
var $prevent_filter_issues = 1;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){}, true);
$(document).ready(filter_optimize);
$(window).on('resize',filter_optimize);

function filter_optimize(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767 && $prevent_filter_issues == 1) {
        window.$prevent_filter_issues = 2;
        var $but_large_small = $('.cat-product-filters .ty-sidebox__body .cm-product-filters').clone().appendTo('#sidebar_filter');
        $('.cat-product-filters .ty-sidebox__body .cm-product-filters').remove();
    } else if ($(window).width() > 766 && $prevent_filter_issues == 2)  {
        window.$prevent_filter_issues = 1;
        var $but_small_large = $('#sidebar_filter .cm-product-filters').clone().appendTo('.cat-product-filters .ty-sidebox__body');
        $('#sidebar_filter .cm-product-filters').remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't restructure HTML or just have duplicate for different media queries? Provide your CSS and HTML

Comment: Well CSS and HTML is not the problem. The content I want to move is a product filter which means that only 1 version of it can be on the page itself, otherwise it would update only the first one in the DOM meaning that you would see a non updated version of the filter on either mobile or desktop.

Comment: @Justinas I fixed it, take a look at the edited post.

Comment: " otherwise it would update only the first one in the DOM". Only if you code it like that. You could code it so that they stay in sync. That said, I've never seen a responsive design before that needed content moving around in the DOM, and rarely ones that required content to be duplicated in multiple locations. It's usually overcomeable with sensible HTML structure and good media queries. Unless you have a very complex design, of course. You say the CSS and HTML is not the problem, but if it wasn't the problem, you wouldn't need this code.

Comment: @ADyson I do need the code, my filters can sometimes be huge meaning that it would take up a lot of space. I also have filters that have images / patterns meaning that those images might load twice on some browsers and not to forget that it also harms your SEO score.